# Symlinking doesn't work in Ubuntu

Tags: linux, ubuntu-14.04, symlink, finder

I tried `ln -s ./storage/profile_pictures/* ./public/profile_pictures/` but that renders my images useless. In my Finder, it says `image.png (alias)`, but in preview it doesn't show the picture, just a white page icon.

How do I fix this?

Comment: What do you actually want to achieve? Link the directory which contains the images to make it accessible under a different name or link each individual picture within that directory into another directory?

Comment: I want the images in storage/profile_pictures/ to be available in public/profile_pictures/ so I can use them in HTML

Comment: So you want to link the *directory* storage/profile_pictures to public/profile_pictures?

Comment: I want the contents of the directory (images) to be available in public/profile_pictures.

So for example storage/profile_pictures/1.jpg should be available in public/profile_pictures/1.jpg

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As morido said, you want `public/profile_pictures` to be a symlink to the directory `storage/profile_pictures`. So don't use `./storage/profile_pictures/*`, because the shell will expand that to a list of all files in `./storage/profile_pictures/`.

Secondly, you're using a relative path:

```
ln -s ./storage/profile_pictures ./public/profile_pictures
```

says "make a symlink in `./public/profile_pictures` that points to `./storage/profile_pictures`". The first argument is relative to the second one. That is, you'd wind up with `./public/profile_pictures/profile_pictures` which points to the directory `./public/profile_pictures/storage/profile_pictures`, which presumably doesn't exist.
The easiest way to do this is likely

```
cd public
ln -s ../storage/profile_pictures profile_pictures
```

Answer (score 0):

You almost got it. The following should work if you want to make a symbolic link from `storage/profile_pictures/` to `public/profile_pictures/`:

```
ln -s storage/profile_pictures public/profile_pictures
```

Note that `public/profile_pictures` must not yet exist.

This link will allow you to access a picture `1.jpg` both as `storage/profile_pictures/1.jpg` and as `public/profile_pictures/1.jpg`

Comment: Unfortunately, it didn't work? I now have an alias to a directory in the Finder, but I can't open it?

http://imgur.com/WkAWUAb

Comment: @jbehrens94 Its hard to tell from your screenshot what you did wrong there. A dump of `ls -l public/` would be a lot more helpful. Perhaps you simply executed the ln command from the wrong subdirectory and thereby created a dead link?